# addObject changes everything with same items

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I want to add icdcodeDictionary into backlist but it changes all elements of backlist.After this process they are same with the last added item. How can I resolve this? I followed this link.http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/88286-adding-object-to-nsmutablearray-changes-all-objects.html
but nothing happened. Thanks.

```
NSMutableDictionary *icdcodeDictionary;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *backlist;
[self.backlist addObject:icdcodeDictionary];
```

Result of

> NSLog(@"backlist %d index: %@",self.backlist.count-2,[icdcodeDictionary objectForKey:@"Name"]);
>
> NSLog(@"backlist %d index: %@",self.backlist.count-1,[icdcodeDictionary objectForKey:@"Name"]):

```
backlist 0 index: Urlar
backlist 1 index: Urlar
```

but I want this:

> ```
> backlist 0 index: Neoplazma
> backlist 1 index: Urlar
> ```

Comment: Please be more descriptive possibly with some NSLogs and example data. "changes all elements" really is not very descriptive, changes how? Also where is `icdcodeDictionary` initialized?

Comment: I edited with some logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same dictionary you're printing. You need to create new one for each `addObject:`.

```
[self.backlist addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:icdcodeDictionary]];
```

Comment: It's because `dictionaryWithDictionary:` creates a new dictionary with the contents of the parameter. In your case you were basically adding the same dictionary multiple times. In objective-c almost everything is a reference to the actual object. These are called pointers and as opposed to primitive types (such as NSInteger) new objects are created only with constructor methods.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got your problem while you are setting dictionary inside forloop you need to write like this code below inside your for loop.

```
// here it is for loop
 for (i=0; i<2; i++)
 {
 // this dictinary needs to call how many times   
 you set object
  NSMutableDictionary * mut= 
 [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
 // now set your object inside dictionary
 }
```

Comment: Now if you print NSLog you will get two different values